# Alternating background color for li in multiple nested ul elements

Tags: html, css

So I'm generating a nested ul from json data. For readability (as well as a design choice) I want to make the background color of each line alternating.

So something looks like this:

[image]

I tried nth-of-type but that only works for the relative index of each li element.
Is there any way to achieve this by pure css without javascript?

EDIT: code for generating the html from json.

might be easier to add a counter in here and apply a separate class.

```
import React from "react"

class InputTree extends React.Component{
    renderChild = (child) => {
        //has children
        if (child.children) {
            return (
                <ul>
                    {child.children.map(item => {
                        return this.renderChild(item);
                    })}
                </ul>
            ); 
        }
        // it's a child node
        else {
            return <li>{child.name}<li/>; 
        }
        return null;
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="inputTree">
                {this.renderChild(this.props.data)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: I am thinking it is going to be a lot more than CSS. You are not going to know how to set a parents sibling based on the length of the siblings children.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is definitely found with `nth-of-type()`
Here is a working example.
https://codepen.io/lukepeters/pen/bfFur

Giving each row `div` a class of `.row` allows you to alter `background:` of either the even or odd rows.
First you set the base `background:` in the the `.row` style.
Then you can alter every other row with `.row:nth-of-type(odd){background:#color}` (or even if you change the word inside the parenthesis to "even")

*you do not have to give your row div a class of `.row`. You can name it whatever you like as ling as they match for each row.

//EDIT//
Since you now have code; you can give your li the above referenced class and write your CSS as mentioned.

Comment: This absolutely does NOT work. I have nested <ul> maybe that wasn't clear enough? nth-of-type only looks at relative index. I'm trying to get it to work with js now lol.

Comment: What does your output html look like?